# Reassign variable of type auto that is currently std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, arduino, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, auto

I am currently experimenting with the ESP32-CAM, which is a microcontroller with integrated camera that you can program through the Arduino IDE (with C++11). For capturing images with the cam, there is a library called 'esp32cam', which contains the function `esp32cam::capture()`. This function apparently returns a variable with the type `std::unique_ptr<esp32cam::Frame>`. There is also an example sketch, which saves the returned frame in a local variable of the type `auto`:

```
auto frame = esp32cam::capture();
```

For my project though, I want to store the last image captured by the cam globally, so I tried this:

```
auto lastPic = std::unique_ptr<esp32cam::Frame>();
void takePicture() {
  lastPic = esp32cam::capture();
}
```

However, that gave me the following error:

```
use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = esp32cam::Frame; _Dp = std::default_delete<esp32cam::Frame>]'
```

I am completely new to C++, so I do not really understand what this means, but as far as I am concerned `std:unique_ptr` manages an object and disposes of it when it does not need it anymore, and since I attempt to add a different object to the variable, it is basically a different unique_ptr and therefore a different type as well, so I cannot assign it.
It could also very well be that I understood this entirely wrong though.

So my question is: How can I reassign this variable?

Any help is appreciated; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
auto lastPic = std::unique_ptr<esp32cam::Frame>();
void takePicture() {
  lastPic = esp32cam::capture();
}
```

to this:

```
auto lastPic = std::unique_ptr<esp32cam::Frame>();
void takePicture() {
  lastPic = std::move (esp32cam::capture());
//          ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

(Because `std::unique_ptr` is moveable but not copyable.)

Comment: It should have worked without `std::move`. If `esp32cam::capture()` is declared the way the OP describes, it returns a temporary, and the plain assignment should have resolved to move assignment operator.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah yes, good point.  OP, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem! I'm not allowed to accept your answer yet, but I will when I can.

Comment: @PaulSanders The one the Arduino IDE uses, I do not know what exactly this is (As I have said, I am completely new to C++) What I know for sure though is that it is C++11 Edit: It seems to be "Atmel gcc".